# Laravel 9 createMany() Child Tables When Parent is Created

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a gardening app for indoor/outdoor home growers. A `run` has many `cultivars` and a `cultivar` belongs to the `run`.

When a user creates a new `run`, they enter how many `cultivars` (plants) are in the run.  The below works when the data is hard coded, but I want the total number of cultivars created based on the amount the user enters in the `run` field.  I know an array needs to be created, but I couldn't figure that part out.

```
public function createRun()
{

    $run = Run::create([
        'tenant_id' => 1,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'cultivars' => 2
    ]);

    $run->cultivars()->createMany([
        ['run_id' => $run->id, 'name' => $run->name . ' ' . 1],
        ['run_id' => $run->id, 'name' => $run->name . ' ' . 2],
    ]);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) to repeat many `create()` calls as required:

```
$run = Run::create([
    'tenant_id' => 1,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'cultivars' => 2
]);


$numberToCreate = $run->cultivars;

for ($i=1; $i <= $numberToCreate; $i++) { 
    $run->cultivars()->create([
        ['name' => $run->name . ' ' . $i],
    ]);
}
```

An alternative that uses the `createMany()` method instead:

```
$numberToCreate = $run->cultivars;

$dataToInsert = [];

for ($i=1; $i <= $numberToCreate; $i++) { 
    $dataToInsert[] = ['name' => $run->name . ' ' . $i];
}

$run->cultivars()->createMany($dataToInsert);
```

The `->create()` and `->createMany()` methods do not require you to set `'run_id' => $run->id` as this is handled automatically (assuming you've set up your Eloquent relationships correctly).

As an alternative, you might also be able to use [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events) to automatically create the required `cultivars` after the `created` event fires for the `Run` model.